# Converting UTF8 to Hebrew

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, hebrew

i'm getting this text from an array cell:

```
$array["cell"] = à¡±á;  þÿ
```

when i do "mb_detect_encoding ( $cell);", i get that it is UTF8.
if its UTF8 , its supposed to show hebrew, but i also read alot of posts here and implemented alot of solution possibilities, but i just can't get to turn that UTF8 text into hebrew. i tried:

```
$retstr = utf8_encode($cell);

$retstr = iconv("UTF-8", "windows-1255", $cell);

$retstr = mb_convert_encoding($cell, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1');

$retstr = iconv(' ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', $cell);

$retstr = iconv('cp1250', 'utf-8', $cell);
```

nothing turns this text into hebrew.

can anyone help?

Comment: If UTF-8 is a valid encoding for hebrew (I think it is, not 100% sure), then the issue is most likely with your file-encoding or the PHP-header. What is your `header` set to (if anything)?

Comment: you are right. this is not an encoding problem. the problem was with the Excel php component that translated the excel hebrew into text format , instead of Excel format. thank you.

Comment: @Rodniko, Do you have an answer for this one? Thanks